# How can I share an automounted USB device (any fs) AUTOMATICALLY via samba?

Tags: networking, usb, mount, samba, automount

Background: I am running Ubuntu on a headless system. I want to be able to attach a usb stick to it and have the stick automatically mounted **and** shared via samba / network. The name of the network share should be the partition label or the UUID if no label exists.

I was thinking about sharing the /media/ directory, but I would prefer to have a solution which shares only the mounted media, not the upper directory.